# SQL Function: Long CASE Statement, Errors all over the place

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to SQL programming, and could write this code all day in C# but suck at it in SQL. So anyway.

I'm trying to send in two int IDs that are used to determine whether the object has "passed" a test or not, then return that so I can send that back in my stored procedure.

There are a lot of things after the then of each statement, but the gist is there. Below is the simplified code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getPPassed]
(
    @pId int,
    @mId int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @passed int;

    SELECT CASE
    WHEN @mId = 1 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 2 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 3 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 4 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 5 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 17 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 7 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 16 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 8 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 9 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 10 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 11 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 12 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 13 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 14 THEN @passed = 1
    WHEN @mId = 15 THEN @passed = 1
    ELSE @passed = 0
    END

    IF @passed = 1 RETURN 1
    ELSE RETURN 0
END
GO
```

Again, any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I have errors saying there's a syntax error near 'ELSE' and 'END', as well as an error on the function itself saying "ALTER FUNCTION must be the only statement in the batch."

Sorry I'm such a SQL noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) - **NOT** a statement - that can return a single, atomic value (from a number of possible values) - it cannot be used to selectively run code fragments.

You need to change your code to

```
SELECT 
    @passed = CASE
                 WHEN @mId = 1 THEN 1
                 WHEN @mId = 2 THEN 1
               ......
```

etc. - **one assignment**, and the `CASE` just provides the various, possible values

Comment: Thank you - you wouldn't believe how happy seeing all the sqigglys go away made me.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more simply phrased as:

```
SELECT @passed = (CASE WHEN @mId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 17, 7, 16, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0
                  END);
```

If you intend a range, it is even simpler:

```
SELECT @passed = (CASE WHEN @mId BETWEEN 1 AND 17
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0
                  END);
```

Comment: Well, there are things I do within the THENs that make it much more complicated. (That's where I use the pId for one. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Anna . . . `CASE` statements do not *do* things in the `THEN` clauses.  They simply return values.